# can server handle this game?

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io, multiplayer

In my web-based multiplayer game which I am using Nodejs and Socket.io,
I want to have some random boxes that player can destroy them. this is what I did:

on server I made a object array that contains random x,y of boxes. when a player connects, server send him the object array and so client render the boxes in client side. 
Now when a player destroy one of the boxes It sends x,y of the destroyed box to server, then server removes that x,y from the object array (for new players) and generate a new x,y (for new box to replace the destroyed box). and finally server send a new object including the destroyed box x,y and the new box x,y And So players render the new box and delete the destroyed box.

Now this is working but since I'm new to making such multiplayer games, I'm not sure if the server can handle this (there is maximum 40 players on a server and there is like 500-800 boxes on map and well this is just one small part of the  game). I'm worried about performance, So will there be any problems? Is there a better way to this? any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the boxes is quite special. In general you should always try to keep scalability in mind and try to split different domains on different services.

But in this special case, I would say it depends on your implementation and of course your server specs. How many boxes are destroyed per second? There are so many unknown variables in your question.

Comment: per second I would say like 10-20 max 30. and for server that is and other reason why i'm asking this, to see what kind of server can handle this

Comment: This sound pretty simple for any server. But also highly depends on your implementation. Does your implementation support parallel processing?
I think nobody can give you a solid answer. Just give it a try with a pretty simple server (local machine) and see how it works out.